# VirtualBox 7 fails on installation process at Ubuntu Desktop 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dpkg, dependencies

For `Ubuntu Desktop` **22.04** to install `VirtualBox 7` was executed the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb
```

But it fails with the following error message

```bash
...
Unpacking manpages-dev (5.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up manpages-dev (5.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Setting up binutils-common:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-101.111) ...
Setting up libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Setting up libasan6:amd64 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libtirpc-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up rpcsvc-proto (1.4.2-0ubuntu6) ...
Setting up make (4.3-4.1build1) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg2-6) ...
Setting up libubsan1:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libnsl-dev:amd64 (1.3.0-2build2) ...
Setting up libcrypt-dev:amd64 (1:4.4.27-1) ...
Setting up libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.11-6) ...
Setting up libbinutils:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Setting up libcc1-0:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up liblsan0:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libc-devtools (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libctf0:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Setting up libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5help5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Setting up libgcc-11-dev:amd64 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.14-161095~Ubuntu~jammy) ...
Adding group `vboxusers' (GID 137) ...
Done.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Setting up binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu (2.38-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Setting up binutils (2.38-4ubuntu2.6) ...
Setting up gcc-11 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up gcc (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/manueljordan/deb/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

The content of the `/var/log/vbox-setup.log` file is:

```bash
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -j4 forced in submake: resetting jobserver mode.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1 
# cmd_mod /tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv.mod
  printf '%s
'   linux/SUPDrv-linux.o SUPDrv.o SUPDrvGip.o SUPDrvSem.o SUPDrvTracer.o SUPLibAll.o common/string/strformatrt.o combined-agnostic1.o combined-agnostic2.o combined-os-specific.o | awk '!x[$0]++ { print("/tmp/vbox.0/"$0) }' > /tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv.mod
# CC [M]  /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  gcc-12 -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -I./ubuntu/include -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -std=gnu11 -fshort-wchar -funsigned-char -fno-common -fno-PIE -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-format-security -Wno-trigraphs -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -mno-80387 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fpatchable-function-entry=16,16 -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-main -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -fzero-call-used-regs=used-gpr -pg -mrecord-mcount -falign-functions=16 -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -g -gdwarf-5 -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -fsanitize=bounds-strict -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c   ; ./tools/objtool/objtool --hacks=jump_label --hacks=noinstr --hacks=skylake --retpoline --rethunk --sls --stackval --static-call --uaccess --prefix=16   --module /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2039: /tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:133: vboxdrv] Error 2
```

How to fix this situation?

**Update 01**

Executing the `sudo apt install build-essential` command as suggested happens

```bash
sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-11 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libstdc++-11-dev lto-disabled-list
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-11-multilib gcc-11-doc bzr libstdc++-11-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-11 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl
  libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libstdc++-11-dev lto-disabled-list
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 54.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libstdc++-11-dev amd64 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [2,101 kB]
Get:2 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 g++-11 amd64 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 [11.4 MB]                                
Get:3 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1 [1,412 B]                                               
Get:4 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libdpkg-perl all 1.21.1ubuntu2.3 [237 kB]                                   
Get:5 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 lto-disabled-list all 24 [12.5 kB]                                                  
Get:6 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 dpkg-dev all 1.21.1ubuntu2.3 [922 kB]                                       
Get:7 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 build-essential amd64 12.9ubuntu3 [4,744 B]                                         
Get:8 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libfakeroot amd64 1.28-1ubuntu1 [31.5 kB]                                           
Get:9 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 fakeroot amd64 1.28-1ubuntu1 [60.4 kB]                                              
Get:10 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.201-1 [41.8 kB]                                       
Get:11 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-6build3 [11.9 kB]                             
Get:12 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-3 [12.0 kB]                                       
Get:13 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libfile-fcntllock-perl amd64 0.22-3build7 [33.9 kB]                                
Fetched 14.9 MB in 16s (943 kB/s)                                                                                                              
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-11-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 210782 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libstdc++-11-dev_11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-11.
Preparing to unpack .../01-g++-11_11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-11 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../02-g++_4%3a11.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdpkg-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libdpkg-perl_1.21.1ubuntu2.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdpkg-perl (1.21.1ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lto-disabled-list.
Preparing to unpack .../04-lto-disabled-list_24_all.deb ...
Unpacking lto-disabled-list (24) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../05-dpkg-dev_1.21.1ubuntu2.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.21.1ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../06-build-essential_12.9ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.9ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libfakeroot_1.28-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../08-fakeroot_1.28-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.201-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.201-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-6build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-6build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-fcntllock-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libfile-fcntllock-perl_0.22-3build7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build7) ...
Setting up lto-disabled-list (24) ...
Setting up libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build7) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.201-1) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.28-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.21.1ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-6build3) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up g++-11 (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.21.1ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up g++ (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (12.9ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
```

My concern that nothing about `gcc-12` appears

Then the `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` command is executed

```bash
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

The content of the `/var/log/vbox-setup.log` file is as follows:

```bash
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -j4 forced in submake: resetting jobserver mode.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1 
# cmd_mod /tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv.mod
  printf '%s
'   linux/SUPDrv-linux.o SUPDrv.o SUPDrvGip.o SUPDrvSem.o SUPDrvTracer.o SUPLibAll.o common/string/strformatrt.o combined-agnostic1.o combined-agnostic2.o combined-os-specific.o | awk '!x[$0]++ { print("/tmp/vbox.0/"$0) }' > /tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv.mod
# CC [M]  /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  gcc-12 -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -I./ubuntu/include -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -std=gnu11 -fshort-wchar -funsigned-char -fno-common -fno-PIE -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-format-security -Wno-trigraphs -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -mno-80387 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fpatchable-function-entry=16,16 -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-main -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -fzero-call-used-regs=used-gpr -pg -mrecord-mcount -falign-functions=16 -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -g -gdwarf-5 -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -fsanitize=bounds-strict -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c   ; ./tools/objtool/objtool --hacks=jump_label --hacks=noinstr --hacks=skylake --retpoline --rethunk --sls --stackval --static-call --uaccess --prefix=16   --module /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2039: /tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:133: vboxdrv] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `gcc-12: not found` makes me suggest you do: `sudo apt install build-essential`. That will install the compiler and friends that you need.

Comment: My post does not have Figures and the error stack trace is formatted. What do you mean with your first part of your answer?

Comment: Added the `Update 01` section. Thanks